# jquery code break if I add a table....anyone can find out why?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, WHICH WORKS JUST FINE...WORKS AS I WANT. But if I place my checkboxes in the table, I get an empty array.

Here is the code:

```
<table border="1">
    <div id="boxes">
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id1"  class="box" value="Banana"> Banana </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id2"  class="box" value="Cherry"> Cherry </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id3"  class="box" value="Strawberry"> Strawberry </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id4"  class="box" value="Orange"> Orange </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id5"  class="box" value="Peach"> Peach </td></tr>
    </div>
</table>
<br /><br />
<div id="chekcAll">
    <input type="button" id="checkThem" value="Check All Checkboxes">
</div>
<br /><br />
<form id="myForm" action="2.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="actualvalue" name="actualvalue" />
    <input type="submit" id="groupdelete" value="clickme"  disabled="disabled"/>
</form>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // this function enable or disable the button on click on the checkboxes
        $(".box").click(function(){
            if($('.box').is(':checked'))  {     
                $('#groupdelete').removeAttr("disabled")
            } else {
                $('#groupdelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        })

        // this is the function for checking/unchecking all checkboxes with the button   
        $('#checkThem').on('click', function(){
            var $boxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
            $unselected = $boxes.not(function(){ 
                return this.checked;
            });
        // if there are any unselected boxes, it selects all, else it deselects all
            $boxes.prop('checked', $unselected.length > 0);
        })

        // this function toggle the Check All Checkboxes button label
        $('#checkThem').click(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "Check All Checkboxes") {
                $(this).val("Uncheck All Checkboxes");
                $('#groupdelete').removeAttr("disabled")
            } else {
                $(this).val("Check All Checkboxes");
                $('#groupdelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });

        // this function send the array to the php page when submit button is clicked
        $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {    
            var names = [];
            $('#boxes').children('input[name="fruit\[\]"]:checked').each(function() {
                names.push($(this).attr("id")); //it better to pass value by using        $(this).val()
            });    
            $("#actualvalue").val(names.join(","));
            $(this).children('input[name="fruit\[\]"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I remove the table arround the checkboxes, code works...that is an array is sent to my page 2.php. Now with the table, I get an empty array. Anyone can shed light on this mystery??

Regards

Comment: It's because jQuery knows that check-boxes are not tabular data :P

Comment: which part of the code is troubling you. I mean what functionality it is? When you check the checkboxes?

Comment: JK btw, jQuery doesn't know that... ;)

Comment: when I submit the form, on the next page, I am getting empty array. If I remove the table, the code works, I am getting an array with selected checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this line

```
  $('#boxes').children('input[name="fruit\[\]"]:checked').each(function() {
```

to this

```
  $('#boxes').find('input[name="fruit\[\]"]:checked').each(function() {
```

`children` only travels a single level,  `find` goes all the way down

from jquery website: "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .children() method allows us to search through the children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well."

more info:  http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 3):

children() returns child-nodes, but the boxes are not child-nodes of the table or #boxes, they are childNodes of the td-elements.

Regarding to the answer by gdoron:

Use a proper markup:

```
<table border="1" id="boxes">
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id1"  class="box" value="Banana"> Banana </td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id2"  class="box" value="Cherry"> Cherry </td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id3"  class="box" value="Strawberry"> Strawberry </td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id4"  class="box" value="Orange"> Orange </td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[]" id="id5"  class="box" value="Peach"> Peach </td></tr>
</table>
```

...and use a simple selector to fetch the boxes, e.g.

```
$('input[name="fruit\[\]"]:checked',
  $('#boxes')).each(/*...*/)
```

(note the 2nd argument for the context, this will force jQuery to find only elements inside #boxes)

Comment: Please suggest him to change the elements name from `fruit[]` to `fruits`... +1

Comment: I wouldn't really suggest this, I would keep them, also keep the boxes inside the form to have a fallback for users with js-disabled(then he would need the braces)

Answer (score 2):

You have nested div element inside the table element.
The only elements that allowed to be nested inside table is thead, tbody, tfoot, tr, th and td.
any other element can be place inside th and td only.

The following correction should set you up:

```
<div id="boxes">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" id="id1" class="box" value="Banana"> Banana</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" id="id2" class="box" value="Cherry"> Cherry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" id="id3" class="box" value="Strawberry"> Strawberry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" id="id4" class="box" value="Orange"> Orange</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" id="id5" class="box" value="Peach"> Peach</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using .children() but div#boxes has no children of type input.
Use .find() instead

```
$('#boxes').find('input...').each...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the table in the div, instead of the other way around? Shouldn't affect the script, but a div is not a valid child of a table.